# how can i use '@' by myself function like '@staticmethod'

Tags: python, decorator

the next is my code,it can print `'xxx'`, but run wrong at last:

```
def a(object):
    print 'xxx'

@a
def b():
    return 'bbb'
b()
```

In your answers, please try to use code examples rather than text, because my English is not very good. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The decorator form `@a` means:

```
@a
def b...
```

is **exactly** the same as:

```
def b...

b = a(b)
```

So, write `a` as a *higher order function*, AKA **HOF**: specifically, a function that takes a function object as an argument, and returns a function object.

As you give **NO** idea in your question about **what** `a` is supposed to **DO**, you're really making it impossible to give a code example that makes any sense whatsoever: good English or not, you're really polluting SO, not contributing to it, by your questions, since you never explain **WHAT** are you trying to accomplish in your code!!!

Comment: +1 even though I hate using ALL CAPS to emphasize things (that's what bold and italics are for).

Answer (score 1):

```
def a(b):
    print 'xxx'
    return b

@a
def b():
    return 'bbb'
b()
```

This is the same as:

```
def a(b):
    print 'xxx'
    return b


def b():
    return 'bbb'

b = a(b)
b()
```